# Generating all possible combinations of elements from different size sets

Tags: r

I have 7 different lists (sets) and I want to generate all the possible combinations possible. For example:

Comment: Can the subelements overlap? Note that a set has no order, so it is probably better to use tuples.

Comment: Great! Good luck with it! If you get stuck, feel free to ask a question with what you've tried and researched. Read [ask] for more guidelines

Comment: Do you use `r` or `python` here?

Comment: `expand.grid(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)` ? (in R)